# Какие речевые ошибки допущены в следующем предложении? Как его исправить?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Примером может служить вековой опыт Шатиловского и Велико-Анадольского лесоповалов, давно заселенных крылатыми друзьями.

Answer (score 2):

Смысл фразы мне непонятен, поэтому исправлять не берусь. Остаются только вопросы и предположения:

Лесоповалы эти существуют веками?

Лесоповалы накопили опыт? Как это понимать? Имеются в виду лесоповалы как предприятия? Если это предприятия, то как они могут быть заселены крылатыми друзьями? Скорее всего, лесоповал — место, а место не может накопить опыт. 
Можно сказать: **опыт, накопленный в лесоповалах**. Возможно, это решит проблему.

Опыт служит примером? Если опыт как совокупность знаний, то он не может служить примером. Если опыт как эксперимент, попытка, то что значит "вековой"? Опыт протяженностью в сто лет? Так и скажите.

Дополнение.

На основании комментариев автора (100 лет тому назад вырубили лес. На этом месте создали лесничества, вновь вырастили деревья, где стали жить птицы), предлагаю такое решение:

**Примером могут служить лесничества, 100 лет тому назад созданные на месте Шатиловского и Велико-Анадольского лесоповалов и давно заселенные крылатыми друзьями.**

или так

**Примером может служить вековая история Шатиловского и Велико-Анадольского лесоповалов, давно превращенных в лесничества и заселенных крылатыми друзьями.**

Comment: Речь, очевидно, идет о лесничествах, созданных на территории бывших лесоповалов.

Comment: Кто накопил вековой опыт? Лесничества? Кажется, слово "вековой" никуда не клеится.

Comment: Безусловно, здесь имеет место быть речевая недостаточность. 100 лет тому назад вырубили лес. На этом месте создали лесничества, вновь вырастили деревья, где стали жить птицы. :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Вызывает сомнение традиция присвоения имени событию вырубки леса. Разве что (из области фантастики) некто Шатилов решил этим какую-то серьёзную проблему и в результате был приравнен Брусилову.
2. "Вековой опыт лесоповала" может иметь только смысл места продолжающейся уже столетие вырубки леса, который пока ещё вырублен не до конца (что-то вроде карьера, в котором что-то добывают по мере надобности).
3. "Лесоповал" в значении ещё не истощившегося "карьера" (см. п. 2) условно можно "заселить", но трудно отделаться от воображаемой картины: птицы особого подвида заселили пространство между пнями.

Поскольку смыслы, вытекающие из написанного не соответствуют желаемому смыслу (который на данный момент раскрыт), можно предложить следующее:

> Примером могут служить лесничества, сложившиеся в местах Шатиловского
>   и Велико-Анадольского лесных массивов после лесоповалов вековой
>   давности: эти места уже давно заселили пернатые.

Comment: Все хорошо, но особенно впечатляет п. 3 :)